# Download any file using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When I was developing a file download api i had almost nothing to make it work in the html page. I searched a lot. In some pages i found some are telling that it's impossible to download using ajax.
But i make it possible using ajax. First convert the file into base64, then use this piece of code as middle ware, this will create anchor tag and on click your element will wrok for any kind of file like doc,docx,xls,xlsx,mp3,mp4..... it can download any kind of file.

```
$(".filled-in").click(function(e) {
    var _this=$(this);
    $file = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: {!! json_encode(url('/download')) !!}, data: {
            '_token' : $("input[name='_token']").val(),
            'file' : $file
        },
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(json) {
           var element = document.createElement('a');
           var fl='data:' + header_content +';charset=utf-8;base64,' +json.content;
            element.setAttribute('href', fl);
            element.setAttribute('download', $file_org_name);
            element.click();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: May I ask, what type of language you are using to build with your API?

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS

```js
const express = require('express')
  ,app = express()
;
app.get('/download/:file*?', (req,res) => {

  // Magic
  ...
  // Redirect your user to the file path, and let them download the file
  res.download(`${__dirname}/${filePath}`);
});
```

JavaScript

```js
// Some kind of click event ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
buttonIGuess.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // Create a invisible iframe for the file downloading
  const iframeElement = document.createElement('iframe');
  // Set the source to your API and as well as the file path
  iframeElement.src = 'https://pony.com/download/rainbow_dash.png';
});
// It should work, if is work :P
```